# ASP/ASP.net: Web-based JET database management tool?

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, jet

I need to manipulate some tables in a JET database housed on a web-server:

- check existing indexes
- change table cluster/primary key
- see what tables exist
- rename tables
- add tables
- drop tables
- browse data
- etc

I don't have the option of installing [PlaneDisaster](http://plane-disaster.sourceforge.net/) or [Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/default.aspx) (even if i had it) on the local machine.

I've already written a generic web-based query tool. I'd rather not have to get into writing a whole web-based database maintenance GUI. Someone must have done this already, and probably many times over.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer might be Compare'Em
http://home.gci.net/~mike-noel/CompareEM-LITE/CompareEMscreens/CompareEM-About.htm  The Pro version allows you to create SQL statements to update the Access database file.   This will allow you to generate the differences between one version and a newer version.

His website isn't very clear but as I recall the price for the Pro version was $10.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have already done a generic web based query tool. The problem with JET is that you cannot connect with it as database server like you can do with one SQL server in order to process changes to tables and other maintenance procedures. Jet is is not a client/server RDBMS. You need to have an application in the server to do that for you as you already have done with your generic web based tool, or download the database to your machine. That's why you have done some procedures and locate them in the server as asp pages.

Anyway you can use [JetSQLConsole](http://www.reevesdigital.com/development/blog/?cat=2), if you don't want to use Planedisaster or Access, but remember that you need always an application on the server to to the job for you

You can also use access "in your machine" and connect to a database located in a URL (http://myserver/mydatabase.mdb) but remember when you are doing this you are downloading all the database and when you save it you are uploading it again.

Comment: +1 for "you cannot connect with a database server in order to process changes to tables and other maintenance procedures. Jet is is not a client/server RDBMS"  i did not know that.

Comment: I edited the phrase to:
"you cannot connect with it as database server like you can do with one SQL server" to make it more readable.

Comment: If you don't know such basics as the fact that Jet is not a client/server database engine, perhaps you shouldn't be using it at all?

Comment: Sorry, dangling modifier. My bad. i didn't know that you can't use DML in JET aside from CREATE TABLE/ADD COLUMN/DROP COLUMN/ALTER COLUMN/ADD CONSTRAINT/CREATE INDEX/CREATE INDEX PRIMARY/DROP INDEX. i did know that Jet is not client server. Jerk.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: you mean SQL DDL (not DML) and your list isn't exclusive e.g. you missed DROP TABLE, ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT, CREATE/DROP VIEW, CREATE/DROP PROCEDURE. Then there's the SQL DCL: ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD, CREATE/DROP GROUP, ADD/ALTER/DROP USER, ADD USER..TO, DROP USER..FROM, GRANT..ON..TO, REVOKE..ON..FROM, BEGIN/ROLLBACK/COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Comment: Yeah, now that i think about it, you can have a web-based managmenet tool. Creating and dropping tables is all you you really need. Next is the ability to get schema info of tables using ADO.net.  i guess i will have to write it.